# JAVA Multiple 'SingleThreadScheduledExecutor' using different threads

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency

I want to run 2 scheduled executors that each run an independent thread.
At the moment this is what I have:

```java
/*
 * Refresh cache periodically.
 */
@PostConstruct
private void refreshCache() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            () -> resellersCache.refresh(this.getClass().toString()), 33, cacheRefreshTimeInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            () -> distributorsCache.refresh(this.getClass().toString()), 33, cacheRefreshTimeInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Does this code create 2 different threads to run these or is it the same thread executing the tasks consequentially?
Thanks

Comment: Each executor has a single thread. You might consider a single executor though (with 2 threads), and creating it so you can shut it down too.

Comment: They are different, this is why you can provide a `ThreadFactory` when creating a new `Executor`.

Comment: @Kayaman, The important detail that sets "SingleThread" executors apart from all others--the reason why it's worth giving them a special name--isn't because of the number of threads that they use. The important bit is that they perform the given tasks _sequentially_, and in the order that the tasks were submitted. I can imagine an application where two single-threaded executors would be appropriate, but a single executor with two threads would not work at all.

Comment: @SolomonSlow a scheduled executor doesn't perform the tasks in the order they were submitted, but in the order they are scheduled to be run. Creating two single thread executors instead of a single 2-threaded executor for scheduling two tasks is just silly. Please provide evidence to back up your imaginary applications, and how they relate to this particular question.

Comment: Javadoc for [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) says, "Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time." Similar language also appears in the Javadoc for the "...Scheduled..." version, though obviously, the Scheduled one will perform tasks in due-date order rather than in the order in which they were submitted.